# JDBC has issues creating users for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I'm trying to create a user in JDBC with

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "password");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String command = "create user 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'pass'";
statement.execute(command);
```

Every time I try to run this I get the error below.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'username'@'localhost'`
```

This I log into mysql as root and the same thing happens. I try the same statement and get `Operation CREATE USER failed for 'username'@'localhost'`. So I then run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and I can then create the user. As soon as I run the program again though the same thing happens.
What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicate that the user already exists or did exist. Thats why you are getting error while creating it

Comment: Does that mean I can't create a user, delete it from the mysql.user table and then re-add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following Steps-

1. Drop the user `DROP USER 'username'@'localhost'`
2. Flush privileges - `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`
3. then Create the user - `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED BY 'Identification'` or `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'`